# Lock a particular cell based on condition

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to lock a particular cell based on some condition on other cell of the same rows. I have done the same in Excel but facing some issue while doing it in Access.

When I am doing it in Access instead of locking a particular cell, it's locking the field.

My requirement is:
[image]

When The ColB is blank, then the comments section cell should locked or disable for any further editing/addition. When it has some value, then it should be unlocked and available for editing.

I have created a form and try to accomplish this. Please let me know if there are any work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *OnCurrent* event of the form:

```
Me!Comments.Locked = IsNull(Me!ColB.Value)
```